# Assign an ID for a part of a paragraph text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a sentence

```
<p>Hello Welcome to SunCity</p>
```

Is it possible to give `SunCity` an id? I tried adding SunCity inside a span but did not work.

The purpose of doing this is that, I need to do a `trigger()` when `SunCity` is clicked.

Comment: `I tried adding SunCity inside a span but did not work` - it should work... what did you try

Comment: You can add like this <p>Hello Welcome to <span>SunCity</span></p>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aehz6ufx/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for your reply. Do you mean `<p>Hello Welcome to <span id="useInTrigger">"SunCity</span></p>` ?

Comment: @Becky see the demo - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aehz6ufx/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny It does. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<p>Hello Welcome to <span id="suncity">SunCity</span></p> 

<script>
   $('#suncity').click(function() {
       alert('It is working');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `span` it should work. Here is a working sample.

```js
$("#myId").click(function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
#myId {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello Welcome to <span id="myId">SunCity</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to click the `SunCity` then you need to wrap it in an element. Then have a click handler for that wrapping element which can trigger the event you want like

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('body').append('<div>Clicked</div>');
});
$('#useInTrigger').click(function() {
  $('button').click()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello Welcome to <span id="useInTrigger">"SunCity</span>
</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Can't we do the same without button , using id of the span?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to place your SunCity inside a `span` tag. Span tag is used for wrapping up any element, It wont break the UI unless you specify some styles to it.

So wrap up your text inside a span and attach a click event to the span using jquery like below.

```
<p>Hello Welcome to <span id="SunCity">SunCity</span></p> 

<script>
   $('#SunCity').on('click',function() {
       alert('Suncity has been clicked!! do your stuff now');
   });
</script>
```